# How to put the url of a custom engine under the url of a page in Refinerycms

Tags: url, url-routing, refinerycms

In Refinary I have two pages "home" and "about". Underneath about there is an engine "news":

- home (page)
- about (page)

  - news (engine)

The default url that the news-engine gets is "/news". Is it possible to use the url "/about/news" instead. I'd like to configure it in such a way that if the engine is moved under another page (eg. "dummy" that the url of the engine is automatically updated to "/dummy/news".

How can this be achieved?